# Plant table, many types of plant, each plant has many attributes, some attributes have multiple values

Tags: python, database, database-design, orm

I have a model that represents a plant. Each plant has a type (flower, tree, shrub, etc.). Each plant type then has differing requirements for a set of attributes, some of which a plant can have multiple values (habitat, regions located, etc.). For example, trees are unlikely to have more than one type of life cycle where as flowers have differing life cycles.

---

How would I go about modeling my data where:

1. All plants are in the same model
2. Enforce a set of attributes on differing plant types

   1. Of those attributes in the set, some of them can have multiple values per plant, but all require at least one.
3. As new plant types are added, the ability to create new attributes, new sets, or reuse old attributes

---

So far, I have a single table for plants, with multiple many-to-many relationships with each attribute in its own table and I would enforce the at least one value in code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Pdf.png

---

I've thought about using Entity-Attribute-Value for the attributes, but then I wouldn't really have the benefit of the ORM I'm using (SQLAlchemy). The same with Serialized LOB.

I think I need Class Table Inheritance, but I'm not sure how to deal with that some of the attributes can have multiple values in an orderly way.

```
Plant                          Habitat
-----    |-->           -->    -------  --> Multiple values per plant
         |
         |      Flower         Life Cycle
         |-->   ------  -->    ---------- --> Single Value
         |
         |      Tree           Cone Type
         |-->   ----    -->    --------- --> Single value
         |
         |      Shrub
         |-->   -----
```

Another possibility is to add attribute tables for each new attribute at run time, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that within SQLAlchemy or any other ORM

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs for [joined table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance).  The plant will a base class, and the flower, shrub, tree can have their own tables.  each of the sub-plant tables can have whatever foreign key relationships are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called [Object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). Speaking loosely, this means that you will be more happy if you don't use inheritance in your database model.

I'm not sure if this is possible/desirable here but:

> Each plant type then has differing requirements for a set of
>   attributes, some of which a plant can have multiple values (habitat,
>   regions located, etc.). For example, trees are unlikely to have more
>   than one type of life cycle where as flowers have differing life
>   cycles.

If you main concern is about *multiplicity* (or [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29) to speak DBA language ;), you don't need inheritance. You only need a "[one-to-many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many)" relationship. For example, each `plant` could be associated to "one-to-many" `life cycle`.

You will really take benefits of inheritance if each sub-set of `plant` add one or many different attributes *meaningless* for its *parent* set.

In that case, you have (at least?) three choices in SQLAlchemy:

- [Single table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance): in that case, at DB level, there is only one table storing any instance of the base class. For each instance, only the required fields are "used"
- [Concrete table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance): in that case, you have one table for each concrete class
- [Joined table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance): you have one table for the base class and some "add-on" tables to add the required attributes for the various sub-classes

The choice on one solution or the other will be guided by your use case -- and how you (and external applications) will query the DB.